# Is it possible to place a malware at an OpenSource resource?

Tags: security, github, pip

Let's imagine I am a very paranoid man. And I am worried about my security. Is it possible to get infected while installing from `GitHub`,`pip`, `gem` or `PPA`. For example, someone got an access to a contributor's password and may change some file. As it has already happend with [Linux Mint at February 21st, 2016](http://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=2994).

How do they check a code when someone is "pushing" it to a repository? What is the probability that there will be a backdoor skillfully hidden inside the code? And what can I do to be sure that I am secure when installing from a low-rated repo, without using virtual-machines?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to place a malware at an OpenSource resource?

Yes, just the same as with closed-source software.

> How do they check a code when someone is "pushing" it to a repository?

That depends on what sort of repository you're talking about, who "they" is, and the specific project.

> What is the probability that there will be a backdoor skillfully hidden inside the code?

Given the vast amount of open-source code available in the world, very low.  What you are worried about, however, is the chance that something *you* download and run will have a known security issue that is then used, and the effect of that vulnerability, which is a different and broader question.

> And what can I do to be sure that I am secure when installing from a low-rated repo, without using virtual-machines?

Read code before you run it - that is the advantage of open-source software.  Otherwise you just have to rely on a nebulous "someone else" to do that for you, as with proprietary software.